# Html Dom with jsoup

Tags: dom, jsoup

I have this html code (part of a long html code) :

```
<div class="yt-lockup-content">
<h3 class="yt-lockup-ellipsize">
    <a class="yt-uix-contextlink yt-uix-sessionlink yt-uix-tile-link result-item-translation-title"dir="ltr"title="Rihanna ft. Calvin Harris - We Found Love LYRICS"data-sessionlink="ved=CAoQvxs%3D&amp;ei=CPLZjMDLwbICFUag3wod7Dm-pw%3D%3D"href="***/watch?v=1KzEu5hWmRY***">Rihanna ft. Calvin Harris - We Found Love LYRICS</a></h3><p class="description " dir="ltr">
        <b>bla</b> ft. Calvin Harris - 
        <b>bla</b> 
        bla bla
        <b>bla bla bla</b> 
        <b>...</b>
        </p><div class="yt-lockup-meta">    
        <ul class="single-line-lego-list">
      <li>    <a href="/results?search_type=videos&amp;search_query=rihanna+we+found+love&amp;high_definition=1" class="yt-badge-std">HD
      </a> 
</h3>
```

And i want to get to this text : href=/watch?v=1KzEu5hWmRY (The bold text).
I know how to get the all line, but how can i grab this text ?
Thanks,
Or.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example:

```
String html = // your html here ...

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

Element element = doc.select("h3[class=yt-lockup-ellipsize] > a").first();
String hrefLink = element.attr("href");
```

However if you want to parse a website, you should use `Jsoup.connect("http://link.com").get()` instead of `Jsoup.parse(html)`